# AJAX Delete action going to the wrong method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to delete a record from the database via an `AJAX` call which looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/Person/DeletePerson',
    data: { personId: personId },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {

        }
    },
    error: function (err, data) {
        alert("Error " + err.responseText);
    }
});
```

This is the method it should enter:

```
public void DeletePerson(int personId)
{
var t = 0; // i'm breaking the debugger right here, never gets hit.
}
```

But Instead, it keeps entering this method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostPerson(dynamic person)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    if (User.Identity.GetUserId() == null)
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Please log in."); 
    }

    return response;
}
```

Both methods reside in a `WebApi Controller`.

`AJAX` `Type: delete` isn't supported. I get this message if I use that instead:

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'delete'
```

How do I get this done?

**EDIT**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the Delete method (since this is a rest implementation) call with the DELETE verb to /api/Person/ URL.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/api/Person',
    data: { personId: personId },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {

        }
    },
    error: function (err, data) {
        alert("Error " + err.responseText);
    }
});
```

Otherwise you need to update the action to accept the delete verb with

```
[HttpDelete]
public void DeletePerson(int personId)
{
var t = 0; // i'm breaking the debugger right here, never gets hit.
}
```

If you want to make the controller look for the id from the JSON payload rather than the request URL, rewrite as the following.

```
public void DeletePerson([FromBody]int personId)
{
    var t = 0; // i'm breaking the debugger right here, never gets hit.
}
```

Comment: In my question I stated that `delete` as a `type` doesn't work with the error msg I get. But this was my initial try, which I gave up trying on.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the webapi routing you are using? Maybe the personId/person parameter causing this behaviour?

Comment: Sure, it's updated. But i'm not using any custom routing, just the standard routing.

Comment: How is the request URL option done? What adjustments do I need to make it work without that `[frombody]`?

Comment: Request to /api/Person/1 where 1 is the id to delete. This will work if the parameter name in routing is the same as that in the method signature, that is personId.

Comment: It still leaves why I get this error message: "The requested resource does not support http method 'delete'"

Comment: Use the attribute [HttpDelete] then.. But this is not good if you are developing a REST service.